# Removing elements from sorted set - ZREM

Tags: redis

I'm removing elements with [`ZREM`](https://redis.io/commands/zrem), however more often than not element is not member of sorted set.

Should I first check with ZSCORE whether element is in set and then proceed with ZREM since former is `O(1)` and thus faster overall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. It makes your code more complicated, and might be slower.

Compared to network RTT (in milliseconds), these two commands run very fast (in microseconds). You can almost ignore the command processing time.

Also, if the element exists, you have to send 2 commands, and get double RTTs. That will be much slower than sending only 1 command.

Yes, you can wrap the logic into a `Lua` script to avoid the extra RTT. However, that makes it more complicated. Also exchanging values between `Lua` and `C` might cost more than the command processing time.